# Can I use v-strings for IPv4 addresses?

Tags: perl, ip-address

The camel book suggests that V-strings can be used for representing IPv4 addresses:

```
$ipaddr = 204.148.40.9;   # the IPv4 address of oreilly.com
```

But [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) on the topic of Version Strings states:

> Note that using the v-strings for IPv4
>   addresses is not portable unless you
>   also use the inet_aton()/inet_ntoa()
>   routines of the Socket package.

I have two questions:

1) Why is using the v-strings not portable?
2) What's the "standard" way to convert an ip-address from dotted notation to integer? Seems that `unpack "N", <v-string>` can cause problems sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "standard" way to get the encoded form is `inet_aton`, which handles dotted IP addresses as well as hostnames -- but what do you need it for? More often than not the best idea is just to skip all of the low-level interfaces that deal with such things and use, e.g., IO::Socket.

If you're looking to convert to *integer*, as you say, and not to the form that socket functions expect (they're similar concepts in C, but less so in Perl), then you can go ahead and use `pack` just fine as long as you're consistent -- the part that's unportable is the format that socket functions accept. For example, `unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, "1.2.3.4"` will get you a nice unsigned big-endian representation of that address (in the form of the number 16909060 == `0x01020304`).